# Is it possible to add a user defined function to CL_SALV_TREE without copying GUI status?

Tags: abap, alv, dynpro

Is it possible to add a user defined function to an instance of `CL_SALV_TREE` without copying GUI status to the report where this instance is used?

What I am trying to do is to add a custom function with `add_function` method.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA: lt_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t000.
    TRY .
      cl_salv_tree=>factory(
        IMPORTING
          r_salv_tree = DATA(lo_salv_tree)
        CHANGING
          t_table = lt_table
      ).
      DATA(lo_salv_functions) = lo_salv_tree->get_functions( ).
      lo_salv_functions->add_function(
        name = 'EXPORT_TO_EXCEL'
        icon = '@J2@'
        tooltip = 'Export as Excel'
        position = if_salv_c_function_position=>right_of_salv_functions
      ).
      lo_salv_functions->set_all( abap_true ).

      lo_salv_tree->display( ).
    CATCH cx_salv_error.
      ASSERT 0 = 1.
    ENDTRY.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

However the button does not appear.

[image: No button]

I remember that I tried to do it some time ago with `CL_SALV_TABLE` and I got an explicit exception when using `add_function`.

What I tried back then was.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA: lt_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t000.
    TRY .
      cl_salv_table=>factory(
        IMPORTING
          r_salv_table = DATA(lo_salv_table)
        CHANGING
          t_table = lt_table
      ).
      DATA(lo_salv_functions) = lo_salv_table->get_functions( ).
      lo_salv_functions->add_function(
        name = 'EXPORT_TO_EXCEL'
        icon = '@J2@'
        tooltip = 'Export as Excel file'
        position = if_salv_c_function_position=>right_of_salv_functions
      ).
      lo_salv_functions->set_all( abap_true ).

      lo_salv_table->display( ).
    CATCH cx_salv_error.
      ASSERT 0 = 1.
    ENDTRY.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

It ends with a short dumped caused by unhandled exception `CX_SALV_METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED`. What I see in the SAP standard code is

```
if lr_controller->r_model->get_display_object( )
                        ne IF_SALV_C_TABLE_OBJECTS=>GRID
  and lr_controller->r_model->get_display_object( )
                        ne IF_SALV_C_TABLE_OBJECTS=>TREE.
  text   = text-001.
  l_name = name.
  raise exception type CX_SALV_METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED
      exporting class  = 'CL_SALV_FUNCTIONS'
                method = 'ENABLE_FUNCTION'
                object = l_name
                key    = text.
endif.
```

From this piece of code one could suppose that it is possible to add a new function with `add_function` method for the object `IF_SALV_C_TABLE_OBJECTS=>TREE`.

So far I used the following workaround.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS lcl_controller DEFINITION FINAL.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES:
      if_salv_csqt_content_manager.
    METHODS:
      constructor.
    DATA:
      mo_salv_tree TYPE REF TO cl_salv_tree,
      mt_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t000.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_controller IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD constructor.
    CALL FUNCTION 'SALV_CSQT_CREATE_CONTAINER'
      EXPORTING
        r_content_manager       = me
        title                   = 'Workaround'.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD if_salv_csqt_content_manager~fill_container_content.
    TRY .
      cl_salv_tree=>factory(
        EXPORTING
          r_container = r_container
        IMPORTING
          r_salv_tree = DATA(mo_salv_tree)
        CHANGING
          t_table = mt_table
      ).
      DATA(lo_tree_settings) = mo_salv_tree->get_tree_settings( ).
      lo_tree_settings->set_hierarchy_header( `Hierarchy` ).
      lo_tree_settings->set_hierarchy_size( 30 ).
      lo_tree_settings->set_header( |{ sy-title }| ).

      DATA(lo_salv_functions) = mo_salv_tree->get_functions( ).
      lo_salv_functions->add_function(
        name = 'EXPORT_TO_EXCEL'
        icon = '@J2@'
        tooltip = 'Export as Excel file'
        position = if_salv_c_function_position=>right_of_salv_functions
      ).
      lo_salv_functions->set_all( abap_true ).

      DATA(lo_salv_nodes) = mo_salv_tree->get_nodes( ).
      DATA(lo_root) = lo_salv_nodes->add_node(
        related_node = space
        relationship = if_salv_c_node_relation=>last_child
        data_row = VALUE t000( mandt = '100' )
        text = `Test`
      ).

      lo_salv_nodes->add_node(
        related_node = lo_root->get_key( )
        relationship = cl_gui_column_tree=>relat_last_child
        data_row = VALUE t000( mandt = '200' )
        text = `Test2`
      ).

      mo_salv_tree->display( ).
    CATCH cx_salv_error.
      ASSERT 0 = 1.
    ENDTRY.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION FINAL CREATE PRIVATE.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      main.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA(lo_controller) = NEW lcl_controller( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

Unfortunately the buttons appear in such case in a different location, directly before the tree and not in the status bar.

[image: Buttons not in the status bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - no, you can't, you need a GUI Status (`CUAD`). You can hide functions at runtime, but you can't add new functions at runtime.